# How to fix oversized Polar Area chart in HTML/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js, rendering

I'm working on a web project that includes a Polar Area chart using the Chart.js library. The chart is supposed to be relatively small, but it's currently being rendered much too large. I've tried changing the canvas size, but it doesn't seem to help.

I'm following a YouTube tutorial and in the video it shows this chart:

[image]

and my chart looks like this:

[image]

**Here's my relevant code:**

**JavaScript:**

```js
let toggle = document.querySelector('.toggle');
let navigation = document.querySelector('.navigation');
let main = document.querySelector('.main');

toggle.onclick = function() {
  navigation.classList.toggle('active');
  main.classList.toggle('active');
}

//ad hovered class in selected list item
let list = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation li');

function activeLink() {
  list.forEach((item) =>
    item.classList.remove('hovered'));
  this.classList.add('hovered');
}
list.forEach((item) =>
  item.addEventListener('mouseover', activeLink));

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'polarArea',
  data: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
  }
});
```

**CSS**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

 :root {
  --blue: #287bff;
  --white: #fff;
  --grey: #f5f5f5;
  --black1: #222;
  --black2: #999;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background: var(--blue);
  border-left: 10px solid var(--blue);
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navigation.active {
  width: 80px;
}

.navigation ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation ul li {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
}

.navigation ul li:hover,
.navigation ul li.hovered {
  background: var(--white);
}

.navigation ul li:nth-child(1) {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.navigation ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--white);
}

.navigation ul li:hover a,
.navigation ul li.hovered a {
  color: var(--blue);
}

.navigation ul li a .icon {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}

.navigation ul li a .icon ion-icon {
  font-size: 1.75em;
}

.navigation ul li a .title {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: start;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


/*curve outs*/

.navigation ul li:hover a::before,
.navigation ul li.hovered a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 35px 35px 0 10px var(--white);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.navigation ul li:hover a::after,
.navigation ul li.hovered a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 35px -35px 0 10px var(--white);
  pointer-events: none;
}


/* main */

.main {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  left: 300px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: var(--white);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.main.active {
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  left: 80px;
}

.topbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.toggle {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.search label {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.search label input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  font-size: 18px;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid var(--black2);
}

.search label ion-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.user {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.user img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.cardBox {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 30px;
}

.cardBox .card {
  position: relative;
  background: var(--white);
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.cardBox .card .numbers {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  color: var(--blue);
}

.cardBox .card .cardName {
  color: var(--black2);
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.cardBox .card .iconBx {
  font-size: 3.5em;
  color: var(--black2);
}

.cardBox .card:hover {
  background: var(--blue);
}

.cardBox .card:hover .numbers,
.cardBox .card:hover .cardName,
.cardBox .card:hover .iconBx {
  color: var(--white);
}


/* charts */

.grapghBox {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.grapghBox .box {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 25px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.details {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  /*margin-top: 10px;*/
}

.details .recentOrders {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  min-height: 500px;
  background: var(--white);
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.cardHeader {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.cardHeader h2 {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: var(--blue);
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: var(--blue);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--white);
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.details table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.details table thead td {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.details .recentOrders table tr {
  color: var(--black1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.details .recentOrders table tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.details .recentOrders table tbody tr:hover {
  background: var(--blue);
  color: var(--white);
}

.details .recentOrders table tr td {
  padding: 10px;
}

.details .recentOrders table tr td:last-child {
  text-align: end;
}

.details .recentOrders table tr td:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: end;
}

.details .recentOrders table tr td:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: center;
}

.status.delivered {
  padding: 2px 4px;
  background: #8de02c;
  color: var(--white);
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.status.pending {
  padding: 2px 4px;
  background: #e0bf2c;
  color: var(--white);
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.status.return {
  padding: 2px 4px;
  background: #e02c2c;
  color: var(--white);
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.status.return {
  padding: 2px 4px;
  background: #e02c2c;
  color: var(--white);
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.status.inprogress {
  padding: 2px 4px;
  background: #2c8fe0;
  color: var(--white);
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.recentCustomers {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  min-height: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: var(--white);
  box-shadow: 0 7px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.recentCustomers .imgBx {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.recentCustomers .imgBx img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.recentCustomers table tr td {
  padding: 12px 10px;
}

.recentCustomers table tr td h4 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.recentCustomers table tr td h4 span {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: var(--black2);
}

.recentCustomers table tr:hover {
  background: var(--blue);
  color: var(--white);
}

.recentCustomers table tr:hover td h4 span {
  color: var(--white);
}


/* responsive design */

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .grapghBox {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    height: auto;
  }
  .navigation {
    left: -300px;
  }
  .navigation.active {
    width: 300px;
    left: 0;
  }
  .main {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
  .main.active {
    left: 300px;
  }
  .cardBox {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .details {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  }
  .recentOrders {
    overflow-x: auto;
  }
  .status.inprogress {
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .cardBox {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  }
  .cardHeader h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .user {
    min-width: 40px;
  }
  .navigation {
    width: 100%;
    left: -100%;
    z-index: 1000;
  }
  .navigation.active {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
  .toggle {
    z-index: 10001;
  }
  .main.active .toggle {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: initial;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Responsive Admin Dashboard | Redesign</title>
<div class="container">
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="logo-apple"></ion-icon></span>
          <span class="title">Brand Name</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="home-outline"></ion-icon></span>
          <span class="title">Dashboard</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="person-outline"></ion-icon></span>
          <span class="title">Customers</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="chatbubble-outline"></ion-icon></span>
          <span class="title">Message</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="help-outline"></ion-icon></span>
          <span class="title">Help</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="settings-outline"></ion-icon></span>
          <span class="title">Setting</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="lock-closed-outline"></ion-icon></span>
          <span class="title">Password</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="log-out-outline"></ion-icon></span>
          <span class="title">Sign Out</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- main-->
  <div class="main">
    <div class="topbar">
      <div class="toggle">
        <ion-icon name="menu-outline"></ion-icon>
      </div>
      <!-- search -->
      <div class="search">
        <label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Search here">
                            <ion-icon name="search-outline"></ion-icon>
                        </label>
      </div>
      <!-- userImg -->
      <div class="user">
        <img src="user.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--cards-->
    <div class="cardBox">
      <div class="card">
        <div>
          <div class="numbers">1,504</div>
          <div class="cardName">Daily Views</div>
        </div>
        <div class="iconBx">
          <ion-icon name="eye-outline"></ion-icon>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div>
          <div class="numbers">80</div>
          <div class="cardName">Sales</div>
        </div>
        <div class="iconBx">
          <ion-icon name="cart-outline"></ion-icon>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div>
          <div class="numbers">284</div>
          <div class="cardName">Comments</div>
        </div>
        <div class="iconBx">
          <ion-icon name="chatbubbles-outline"></ion-icon>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div>
          <div class="numbers">$7,842</div>
          <div class="cardName">Earnings</div>
        </div>
        <div class="iconBx">
          <ion-icon name="cash-outline"></ion-icon>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!--Add charts-->
    <div class="grapghBox">
      <div class="box">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

      </div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="details">
      <!-- order details list -->
      <div class="recentOrders">
        <div class="cardHeader">
          <h2>Recent Orders</h2>
          <a href="#" class="btn">View All</a>
        </div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>Price</td>
              <td>Payment</td>
              <td>Status</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Star Refrigerator</td>
              <td>$1200</td>
              <td>Paid</td>
              <td><span class="status delivered">Delivered</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Windows Coolers</td>
              <td>$110</td>
              <td>Due</td>
              <td><span class="status pending">Pending</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Speakers</td>
              <td>$620</td>
              <td>Paid</td>
              <td><span class="status return">Return</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Hp Laptop</td>
              <td>$110</td>
              <td>Due</td>
              <td><span class="status inprogress">In Progress</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Apple Watch</td>
              <td>$1200</td>
              <td>Paid</td>
              <td><span class="status delivered">Delivered</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Wall Fan</td>
              <td>$110</td>
              <td>Paid</td>
              <td><span class="status pending">Pending</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Adidas Shoes</td>
              <td>$620</td>
              <td>Paid</td>
              <td><span class="status return">Return</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Denim Shirts</td>
              <td>$110</td>
              <td>Due</td>
              <td><span class="status inprogress">In Progress</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Casual Shoes</td>
              <td>$575</td>
              <td>Paid</td>
              <td><span class="status pending">Pending</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Wall Fan</td>
              <td>$110</td>
              <td>Paid</td>
              <td><span class="status pending">Pending</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Denim Shirts</td>
              <td>$110</td>
              <td>Due</td>
              <td><span class="status inprogress">In Progress</span></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      <!-- New Customer -->
      <div class="recentCustomers">
        <div class="cardHeader">
          <h2>Recent Customers</h2>
        </div>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td width="60px">
              <div class="imgBx"><img src="img1.jpg" alt=""></div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <h4>David<br><span>Italy</span></h4>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="60px">
              <div class="imgBx"><img src="img2.jpg" alt=""></div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <h4>Muhammad<br><span>India</span></h4>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="60px">
              <div class="imgBx"><img src="img3.jpg" alt=""></div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <h4>Amelia<br><span>France</span></h4>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="60px">
              <div class="imgBx"><img src="img4.jpg" alt=""></div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <h4>Olivia<br><span>Usa</span></h4>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="60px">
              <div class="imgBx"><img src="img5.jpg" alt=""></div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <h4>Amit<br><span>Japan</span></h4>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="60px">
              <div class="imgBx"><img src="img6.jpg" alt=""></div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <h4>Ashraf<br><span>India</span></h4>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="60px">
              <div class="imgBx"><img src="img7.jpg" alt=""></div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <h4>Diana<br><span>Malasia</span></h4>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="60px">
              <div class="imgBx"><img src="img8.jpg" alt=""></div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <h4>Amit<br><span>India</span></h4>
            </td>
          </tr>

        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.8.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="my_chart.js"></script>
```

**Things I've tried:**

- Setting the `width` and `height` attributes of the `<canvas>` tag to various sizes.
- Experimenting with `options.responsive` in the Chart.js configuration.

I'm not sure what else to try. **Could someone please help me figure out how to make my Polar Area chart smaller?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chartjs canvas fills the width of the parent element. Try adding width value to the parent element of the canvas via style attribute or css. Something like:

```
  <div class="box" style="width: 200px;">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

  </div>
```

If you are using bootstrap, you may try adding proper `col` classes to the parent element instead of using explicit width values so you may keep it responsive.